# How to fix AVAudioPlayer issue in my code?

Tags: ios, xcode

Thanks for visiting this question.

I recently started learning swift. I'm making an audio player ish app.

The nextButton works only for a couple of times, and then it just becomes silent. I'm trying to make an array loop over and over if nextButton is being pressed. So, it means when I press the "next" button, it will go to the next track and if tracks from array finished, it will play all track over again.

All I'm trying to achieve it to get the "next" button work without any stops.

Array and Audio Player:

```
let sound1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "mp3")!)
let sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "2", ofType: "mp3")!)
let sound3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "3", ofType: "mp3")!)

lazy var soundArray: [NSURL] = [sound1, sound2, sound3]
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var run = true
var currentIndex = 0

func playRandomSound() {

        let randNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(soundArray.count)))

        if run == true{
        do {

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundArray[randNo] as URL)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
 }
```

nextButton:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
currentIndex = indexPath.row
}

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
    audioPlayer.stop()
    print("Audio did stop")
        if currentIndex + 1 < soundArray.count {
            currentIndex += 1
            playRandomSound()
    }
}
```

Full Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

extension UILabel {
    func pushUp(_ text: String?) {
        let animation:CATransition = CATransition()
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        animation.type = CATransitionType.push
        animation.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
        animation.duration = 1

        self.layer.add(animation,  forKey: CATransitionType.push.rawValue)
        self.text = text
    }
}

class HideShow: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var moveOn: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Logo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var BGimage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var LayDown: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var audioChanger: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonView: UIView!

    let notification = NotificationCenter.default
    let toImage = UIImage(named:"BG2.jpeg")

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
            self.LayDown.alpha = 1
        }

        UIView.transition(with: self.BGimage,
        duration: 1,
        options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
        animations: { self.BGimage.image = self.toImage },
        completion: nil)

        LayDown.pushUp("CLOSE YOUR EYES")

        self.nextButton.isHidden = true
        self.nextButton2.isHidden = false
    }

    let sound1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "mp3")!)
    let sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "2", ofType: "mp3")!)
    let sound3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "3", ofType: "mp3")!)

    lazy var soundArray: [NSURL] = [sound1, sound2, sound3]
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var run = true
    var currentIndex = 0

    func playRandomSound() {

            let randNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(soundArray.count)))

            if run == true{
            do {

                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundArray[randNo] as URL)
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
     }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped2(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.nextButton2.alpha = 0
            self.LayDown.alpha = 0
            self.nextButton.alpha = 0
            self.BGimage.alpha = 0
            self.moveOn.alpha = 0
            self.Logo.alpha = 0
            self.audioChanger.isHidden = false
            self.buttonView.isHidden = false
        }
            playRandomSound()
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       currentIndex = indexPath.row
    }

    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        print("Audio did stop")
            if currentIndex + 1 < soundArray.count {
                currentIndex += 1
                playRandomSound()
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions,
Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need to dispose of the player before creating a new one.

Comment: @xTwisteDx I have only one view controller. Like, everything happens in one place.